# Package to simulate a computer?

Tags: numerics, packages

The post [Where can I find good textbooks for Numerical Methods in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156774/where-can-i-find-good-textbooks-for-numerical-methods-in-mathematica) reminded me that at one time there was a *Mathematica* package where you could simulate a hypothetical computer: you could specify the number of bits that the machine used for the mantissa and exponent, etc., then do calculations as if you were using that machine.

What is that package and is it still available? (Or has it been subsumed by built-in functions?)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referring to the [ComputerArithmetic package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputerArithmetic/tutorial/ComputerArithmetic.html).